# PHP - WebCalendar - hide field based on dropdown list selection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Using the WebCalendar app http://www.k5n.us/webcalendar.php and I'm creating some custom edits for the way extra fields work.

Particularly, I have two extra fields created; one of them being a dropdown list of counties, and the other being a text field. One option in the dropdown list is `**OTHER` and the text field is there for the user to specify their `**OTHER` selection.

I can specify the dropdown list and selection in PHP with the following:

```
if ($site_extras[1][3] == '**OTHER' )
  { do something to hide html class .other_field }
```

Any hints or pushes in a direction that I may look into for hiding/showing the text field based on the dropdown list input?

Please edit and remove/add tags as necessary. I just selected ones that may be relevant for the needs of this operation.

EDIT: Html snippet

```
<table class="extra_table" summary="">
            <tr>
              <td class="aligntop bold">*Location:</td>
              <td class="extra_field_input">
                <select name="County">
                  <option value="Select County...
"  selected="selected">Select County...

</option>
                  <option value="DODGE" >DODGE
</option>
                  <option value="DOUGLAS" >DOUGLAS
</option>
                  <option value="LANCASTER" >LANCASTER
</option>
                  <option value="MADISON" >MADISON
</option>
                  <option value="**OTHER" >**OTHER
</option>
                  <option value="--------------------" >--------------------

</option>
                  </select>

                </td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="aligntop bold">**If Other, Please Specify:</td>
              <td class="extra_field_input">
                <input type="text" size="17" name="Other_County" value="" />
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: The field would need another defining characteristic other than a non unique class. I don't see where PHP comes into this, this sounds like it would need handling with JS alone. To do that, it would be better for you to post up a snippet of the generated HTML.

Comment: If anyone is willing to look at the edit files for the program, you can download it at the link in the question, and look for files edit_entry.php, and site_extras.php. Do a string search for EXTRA_ in the files and it should get you close. I know most won't however and this problem is a drag =/

Comment: @DavidBarker is targetting via `input name` and `option value` possible? Excuse my ignorance as I'm a beginner with php/javascript/jquery.

Comment: I don't understand what part of this was not addressed in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918476/php-if-dropdown-selection-something

Comment: Hmmmmmmm.... I've just spent a while trying to help you out and you've already had the answer!!!

Comment: @JeffreyBlake I suppose its because I gave all the detail of my project with examples in this question, so it allowed people to help create a live example based on the code I have available to me. I didn't want to just update the old question as it had been sitting for a couple of days, and people may just overlook it. I can use all the help I can get pertaining to Javascript as I know negative-nothing about utilizing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bt8D/

I had to add an extra class to your text field to differentiate it `extra`, and set your input / text field to `style="display:none;"` to start. If that is possible within the limitations of the framework you are using, you're on to a winner. (NOTE: There are definitely better ways to write the Jquery!)

Jquery statement:

```
$(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {        
        var selectValue = $(".extra_field_input select").val();

        if (selectValue == "**OTHER") {
            $(".extra_field_input input").show();
            $(".extra").show();
        } else {
            $(".extra_field_input input").hide();
            $(".extra").hide();
        };
    });
});
```

HTML required

```
<table class="extra_table" summary="">
<tr>
    <td class="aligntop bold">*Location:</td>
    <td class="extra_field_input">
         <select name="County">
              <option value="Select County..." selected="selected">Select County...</option>
              <option value="DODGE" >DODGE</option>
              <option value="DOUGLAS" >DOUGLAS</option>
              <option value="LANCASTER" >LANCASTER</option>
              <option value="MADISON" >MADISON</option>
              <option value="**OTHER">**OTHER</option>
         </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td class="aligntop bold extra" style="display:none;">**If Other, Please Specify:</td>
    <td class="extra_field_input">
          <input style="display:none;" type="text" size="17" name="Other_County" value="" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: each table is autogenerated with PHP, and for all tables with class="extra_table", all of the classes are generated with the same names, and I have no control over pulling out only one of them to change its class.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid without any unique hooks to a specific element you severely limit your ability to manage any javascript specific to that element. Leaving you with very few options.

Comment: I discovered that Jquery works with webcalendar, and I'm going to edit the main .php file that controls the HTML generated page to create class `extra` with an incremented value for each one so it'll show up as `extra1` `extra2` etc. So i'll be testing this hopefully today and I'll report back.

Comment: I'm being held back on my projects atm so it may be a little while before I'm able to test it. But I have a good track record of voting/following up on my questions.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Unfortunately, the change function does not work because the page doesn't update what the selected option is in the select field until after submission. Not sure why as this isn't my program. But I used the click function instead and targeting the whole page so every time the user clicks, it will fire the jquery statement. I also assigned classnames to the parent <tr> so that I can just use the show/hide function on the <tr> instead of the two invdividual <td>. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the `.change` listener will fire if implemented properly for any HTML / XHTML generated select box. I'm going to assume that this framework operates with a standard DOCTYPE?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, .change function will look at the html for the element you have chosen (in this case "select") and if the value changes, it fires an event. Using firebug, I noticed that when I change my dropdown selection, the HTML does not actively update the select element with the currently chosen dropdown item. I read up on .change function as well, and in this scenario it is SUPPOSED to work, and I would rather it work in this manner, but for some reason it doesn't for reasons I am unsure of.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`